# ipython filepath autocompletion: string closing quotation insertion

Tags: string, autocomplete, path, ipython

If I start to type in a filepath by itself, and tab complete it, it works great, i.e.

```
In [1]: ~
[TAB]
In [1]: /Users/zhermes/
```

But if it's inside a quotation, it also auto-closes the quotation, i.e.

```
In [2]: "~
[TAB]
In [2]: "/Users/zhermes/"
```

which makes it annoying to continue inserting more path...
Is there anyway to disable this behavior?

---

Edits:
*Note: this is ipython [issue #1172](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1172).*
**Workaround**: Close the quotes ***before*** starting to enter the path, then tab-completion won't need to close it.  i.e.

```
In [1]: ""
In [1]: "~[TAB]"
In [1]: "/Users/DilithiumMatrix/"
```

Comment: Why don't you avoid the initial quote and tab-complete to your heart, then add the quotes at start and end?

Comment: @Avid because that's also annoying.  But it's certainly better than what I'm currently doing -- so good idea for a stop-gap.

Comment: You don't say which version you're using.  I just tried this with a new installation of ipython 2.3 (current as of November 2014) and autocomplete does not close the quote.

Comment: Version 2.4 here, it does close the quotation. However, you can also let it do it and then step back one character (just before the closing quotation mark) and keep tab-completing with joy. The closing quotation will still be there one character ahead of you cursor, but I guess that if you opened a quotation you'll eventually need the other half... :-)

Comment: Ipython 3.0 exhibits the same behavior that @zhermes has described.  Also, as of late 2014, [the bug has been closed, and it appears that there is no motivation to rectify it.](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7352)

Comment: @AGS sorry for the late response, but for the record the [underlying **issue (#1172) is still open**](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1172), with no recent attention.

Answer (score 1):

IPython 5 (which now uses prompt_toolkit and has many changes to how completions work) appears to fix this. If I type `"~<TAB>` it completes my home directory without inserting a closing quote.

Comment: Awesome.  The new terminal interface looks amazing!